# Wrong transaction manger is being used in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, spring-kafka

I have two spring transaction managers.

1. **txManager1** - ChainedKafkaTransactionManager (KafkaTransactionManager,JpaTransactionManager) configured with datasource DB1
2. **txManager2** - JpaTransactionManager configured with datasource DB2

The problem is that I perform some operation using txManager2 but somehow txManager1 is being used instead of txManager2 and the data is getting committed to DB1 instead of DB2.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("common-tx")
private PlatformTransactionManager txManager2 ;

@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.name}", groupId = "group-1", containerFactory = "customKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void topicListener(String message, Acknowledgment ack)
        throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {


    DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    def.setName(domainEvent.getEventId());
    def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

    TransactionStatus commonStatus = txManager2 .getTransaction(def);

    someService.doSomething();

    txManager2 .commit(commonStatus);


    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

In `doSomething()` I am just persisting an entity, upon debugging it is found that while saving the entity via Spring data repository, the transaction manager 
 determined in `invokeWithinTransaction()` of `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport` is wrong, i.e. txManager1 is selected instead of txManager2, is it a configuration issue or am I missing something?

**txManager1 configuration :**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"})
    @Profile({"development","production","qa"})
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"xxx.xxx.xxxx"},excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX, pattern="xxx.xxx.xxxx.module2.*"))
    public class JPAConfig1 {

    @Value("${jndi.name}")
    private String jndiName;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String showSql;

    @Value("${hibernate.format_sql}")
    private String formatSql;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hiberanteUpdate;

    @Value("${javax.persistence.validation.mode}")
    private String hibernateValidation;



    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl tenantConnection, CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver)
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emf.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties(tenantConnection, currentTenantIdentifierResolver));
        emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"xxx.xxx.xxxx"});

        return emf;
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl tenantConnection, CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",hibernateDialect);        
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",showSql);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql",formatSql);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",hiberanteUpdate);
        properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode",hibernateValidation);

        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolver);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, tenantConnection);

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver getCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver(TenantContext tenantContext) {
        return new CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl(tenantContext);
    }

    @Bean(name="tenantConnection")
    public MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl getMultiTenantConnectionProvider(TenantContext tenantContext) {
        return new MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl(false,tenantContext);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory,ProducerFactory producerFactory){

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(factory);
        KafkaTransactionManager tm = new KafkaTransactionManager(producerFactory);

        return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager(tm,transactionManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TenantContext getTenantContext() {
        return new TenantContextImpl();
    }
}
```

**txManager2 configuration :**

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="xxx.xxx.xxxx.module2",
 entityManagerFactoryRef="common-factory",transactionManagerRef="common-tx")
 @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:common-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"})
 @Profile({"development","production","qa"})
 public class JPAConfig2 {

@Value("${common.jndi.name}")
private String jndiName;

@Value("${common.hibernate.dialect}")
private String hibernateDialect;

@Value("${common.hibernate.show_sql}")
private String showSql;

@Value("${common.hibernate.format_sql}")
private String formatSql;

@Value("${common.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
private String hiberanteUpdate;

@Value("${common.javax.persistence.validation.mode}")
private String hibernateValidation;

@Bean(name="common-factory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("common-ds") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"xxx.xxx.xxxx.module2"});

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("common");
    return em;
}

@Bean("common-ds")
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(jndiName);
}

private Properties jpaProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",hibernateDialect);        
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",showSql);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql",formatSql);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",hiberanteUpdate);
    properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode",hibernateValidation);

    return properties;
}

@Bean(name="common-tx")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("common-factory") EntityManagerFactory factory){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(factory);

    return transactionManager;
}



}
```

Comment: You have to specify the tx manager to use in the `@Transactional` annotation. If your `someService.doSomething` is annotated and without explicit configuration it will use the default. Judging from the fact that you are doing manual tx management here it shouldn't be actually annotated at all. Unless the class has methods mixing different tx-managers then you still need to  expllicitly configure which tx manager to use (and then you should remove the manual tx management).

Comment: I tried both manual & @Transactional annotation, in both cases the result is the same

Comment: If you don't specify WHICH tx manager to use in the `@Transactional` it will always use the default. You MUST specify which one to use. The fact that the wrong one is selected is simpy because you only have `@Transactional` and not `@Transactional("txManager2")`. No matter how much manual tx-management you throw at it, without that it will always use the default.

Comment: I already tried annotating `doSomething()` with `@Transactional(value="common-tx",propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Comment: In manual transaction also I am injecting the respective txManager only via `@Autowired @Qualifier("common-tx") private PlatformTransactionManager commonTXManager;`

Comment: Then there is in the stack somewhere an `@Transactional` without the specific name. If you remove the `@Transactional` and the tx-manager still kicks in, there is another annotation somewhere which selects the default tx-manager.

Comment: Yes the save() method of `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository` is annotated   with `@Transactional`  but it should propogate the existing transaction, no?